# Tableview - NSMutableDictionary - currow get integer value? iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutabledictionary

How do I get the value of the ID into an Integer.  See below:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSMutableDictionary *curRow = [myData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"Cell Click  %@ %@  -  %@",[curRow objectForKey:@"Name"], [curRow objectForKey:@"ID"], [curRow objectForKey:@"DOB"]);

    UserID= [curRow [objectForKey:@"ID" intValue]  ;  <<<< This doesnt work?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the ID is in the dictionary a string you could use

```
UserID = [[curRow objectForKey:@"ID"] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax wrong.

```
UserID= [curRow [objectForKey:@"ID" intValue]  ;  <<<< This doesnt work?
```

use below

```
UserID= [[curRow objectForKey:@"ID"] intValue]  ;  <<<< This will work?
```